# Solr custom filter TokenStream issue

Tags: solr, lucene

For indexing and querying I need to perform certain transformations as listed below. Therefore I wrote a custom filter. How can I perform the concatenation of the token and it get passed to NGramFilterFactory filter. Please tell me what needs to be improved in the code.

This is the config from schema.xml file:

```xml
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="custom_stop_words.txt"/>
    <filter class="intuit.ripple.solr.ConcatFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="3" />
```

Here is an example of the use case I am trying to solve:

```
1. Input value: "foo Bar Baz qux"
2. WhitespaceTokenizerFactory: "foo", "Bar", "Baz", "qux"
3. LowerCaseFilterFactory: "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"
4. TrimFilterFactory, TrimFilterFactory and StopFilterFactory have nothing to do in this case.
5. ConcatFilterFactory: "foobarbazqux". It should concatenate the tokens.
6. NGramFilterFactory: This will generate the token.
```

Here is the `incrementToken()` method from ConcatFilter:

```java
@Override
public boolean incrementToken()  throws IOException  {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    while (input.incrementToken()) {
        int len = charTermAtt.length();
        char buffer[] = charTermAtt.buffer();
        builder.append(buffer, 0, len);
        System.out.println("Tokens: " + new String(buffer, 0, len));
        clearAttributes();
        charTermAtt.setEmpty();
    }
    System.out.println("Concat tokens: " + builder.toString());

    charTermAtt.copyBuffer(builder.toString().toCharArray(), 0, builder.length());
    charTermAtt.setLength(builder.length());
    posIncAtt.setPositionIncrement(1);
    setOffsetAttr.setOffset(0, builder.length());

    input.end();
    input.close();
    return false;
}
```

Here I am using while loop to fetch all the token and joining them together. Is there any way to fetch all the token at once without looping?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr Custom Filter for cancatnating tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560110/solr-custom-filter-for-cancatnating-tokens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to do something else than you implemented :D

What you do in incrementToken method is just iterating through whole input (in this case output from StopFilter). In each call of increment token you should just take single (or more if needed) token from input and you produce SINGLE token to output.

So I guess you didn't want to use "while" loop here and moreover call "clearAttributes()" in each interation.

I also guess you have ouput like this:

```
Tokens: foo
Tokens: bar
Concat tokens: foo bar
```

But in fact from two tokens "foo" and "bar" you produced single token "foo bar" which I guess was not your intention. Please describe what your ConcatFilterFactory should do. Currently it is only merging multiple tokens to single one.

You have an example of discussion about TokenFilter here: http://search-lucene.com/m/ukJmjphJte/tokenfilter&subj=custom+TokenFilter. You can use this search box to find more information about Solr/Lucene related information: http://search-lucene.com/

Comment: No. I want to concatenate the tokens coming from StopFilter. e.g Tokens from StopFilter are "foo" and "bar" then I want to concatenate them as single token "foobar" as pass it to "NGramFilterFactory" class.

Comment: So please maybe return `true` in first pass and `false` in second call of incrementToken method

Comment: But how I can retrieve all the token (e.g. foo and bar both) in first call and concatenate them. I have very little understanding of TokenStream and Filters. Can you please provide me some code (pseudo) code for this.

Comment: You do it correctly (I mean retrieving all tokens in first call). Please only try to add field to your class (eg. `boolean hasMoreTokens = true;`). When you first run incrementToken please return true and change `hasMoreTokens` to false.

`...`
`boolean hasMoreTokens = true;`
`...`
`public boolean incrementToken()  throws IOException  {`
`...`
`if (hasMoreTokens) {`
`hasMoreTokens = false;`
`return true;`
`} else {`
`return false;
}` Sorry, writing code in comment is not easy

Comment: The problem I see is, how can i fetch all the token at once? I have added an example to questions. Hope that helps in understanding better the problem.

Comment: I'll repeat that it seems you "fetch all the token at once" but when you fetch them you return "false" so next TokenFilters which are in the flow won't read output from your TokenFilter because you returned false. You should return true and in next pass you should return false. That's why I gave such an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to fetch all the tokens at once, you need looping just like in your code. But you can use different approach. Instead of using `solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` use `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory`. `KeywordTokenizerFactory` puts in token stream only one token which is exact input value. Then in your `ConcatFilter` you just take the first and only token from token stream and replace all whitespaces in it to empty string. In this scenario you need to put `StopFilter` after `NGramFilter`. Using your example you will have:

```
1. Input value: "foo Bar Baz qux"
2. KeywordTokenizerFactory: "foo Bar Baz qux"
3. LowerCaseFilterFactory: "foo bar baz qux"
4. ConcatFilterFactory: "foobarbazqux".
5. NGramFilterFactory: This will generate the token.
6. StopFilterFactory cuts all unwanted tokens.
```